# hide css class delete_icon with reference/using button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

template.html

```
 <td style="width:150px;"><input type="button" name="delete"  value="{{ report_person.report_person.id}}" class="delete_icon" />{{report_person.report_person.name }}
 </td>
```

The above row is created dynamically using python/django.Its the person name and delete icon.
For every row created dynamically,the delete icon will appear.

```
<td class="ir-shade" colspan="4"><button id="{{report_person.report_person.id}}" type="button" class="add_treatment" class="button_style">Add treatment notes</button>
<div id="result-{{report_person.report_person.id}}"  class="toggle"></div></td>
```

`Add treatment notes` is a toggle button,it show the treatment details on one toggle,at this state the name of button become `Hide treatment notes`.

I want to hide the delete_icon class for individual name when the treatment note is open f.Since i am using comman css class for delete_icon,using this  `$('.delete_icon').hide();` is hiding the delete icon for all rows created dynamically.Only unique thing is the value of that delete button,that means the delete_icon.Is any possibility is their to hide the css class icon with reference to value.So that the delete image will hide only for cases the treatment notes are in open condition.

Note:It is some django code are used for passing variable,looks different from html.

Comment: is the delete icon in the following result div?

Comment: @AdrianTrainor delete icon is in a <td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, you can use `this` to find [child elements](http://api.jquery.com/children/). Assuming that this is all in one div, or span, or some sort of container. You could simply search downwards from that container and toggle off your delete button.

```
$(this).children("input.delete_icon").hide();
```

Going off of your supplied template, you would use children and also [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to navigate up your DOM, and then back down.

Your code will roughly be:

```
$(this).closest('tr').prev().children(":first").children('input.delete_icon').hide();
```

Let's walk through this:

- `$(this)` is your currently 'clicked' table row, that includes your
  `add_treatment` button.
- `.closest('tr')` looks UP for the nearest
  table row. It will find the table row that your button is placed
  inside of
- `.prev()` looks for the previous *sibling*  of the selected
  object. Since we are currently selecting the `<tr>` your button is in
  (as per our `.closest('tr')`) it will look for the previous `<tr>`
  which is above it, and holds your delete_icon button.
- Now, we are on the `<tr>` of your button object, but we need to navigate downwards
- `.children(":first")` will navigate to the first child of the current element. This would be your first `<td>` element.
- We need to navigate down one more, so we select the button child by using `.children('index.delete_icon')`
- You have now "selected" your `.delete_icon` button, and can `.hide()` it.

Comment: `closest` may also work here, depending on how the entire row is set up. Without seeing the whole table row it's difficult to figure out the perfect selector.

Comment: Jckelley,in the updated answer,the container_class refers to what in my <td>,sorry if it a silly question.

Comment: Of what you have explained about your project so far, I believe it would be the class of your <tr>. Look at closest, as per the updated answer. That may  help you understand it better.

Comment: @JcKelley i applies the 3rd one in my application,changes is not happening i.e delete_icon is not hidden

Comment: Can you post the JS you tried too? More code we see the better (most of the times)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32764/discussion-between-jckelley-and-user2086641)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery .find() function.

```
$('.add_treatment').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('input[class*='delete_icon']').prop('disabled', true);
    // toggle notes
    // hide delete icon (if you do not like the css below)
});
```

Adding css rules would help reduce the amount of javascript functions/actions needed.

```
tr td .delete_icon {
    display:none;
}
tr:hover td .delete_icon {
    display:block;
}
```

There are other ways to do this that are more efficient but we would need more html structure.

Answer (score 0):

if the delete icon is in the following td (created dynamically) you need:

```
$('.add_treatment').click(function(){
    // should point to the parent td, the next td, its children,
    // and hide the first child which is the input button
    $(this).parent().next().children('.delete_icon').hide();
});
```

Comment: `.closest('td')` is redundant here, isn't it? It would just select itself. Closest() starts with itself, then searches up the DOM tree...